# synchronously executing functions in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angularjs 1.0 in my application.
I have a drop down on my cshtml page

```
<select tabindex="2" id="Employee" ng-model="models.SelectedEmployee" ng-change="changeEmployee()" disabled="disabled" class="Answer" size="6">
<option value="-1" selected="selected">Select</option>

<option ng-repeat="option in models.Employees | orderBy:'EmployeeName'" value="{{option.EmployeeKey}}"> {{option.EmployeeName}} - {{option.EmployeeKey}}</option>

</select>
```

On change of Employee, i am calling a function changeEmployee()

```
 $scope.changeEmployee = function () {

$scope.ClearMessages(); //function to clear message displayed in label field (lblMessage)
$scope.FetchAllEmployeeData(); //fetch Employee details like address, dependents details 


}
```

FetchAllEmployeeData function pulls emaployee details from database and if details are presents in databse, adds messages in label field (lblMessage) e.g. Address Details Found, Dependents details Found.

Everything works fine when user selects a Employee name from dropdown. But when user uses down key button to quickly go through each Employee, FetchAllEmployeeData function keeps on adding messages for every employee.
I think this is because FetchAllEmployeeData does not wait for ClearMessage function to complete.

Please help me to handle this scenario.

Comment: please create a fiddle will he helpful to fix

Comment: if FetchAllEmployeeData function is using $http, then ClearMessages() call  move inside $http.success of FetchAllEmployeeData ...

Comment: Thanks 이동권!! Its working now.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand `$scope.FetchAllEmployeeData();` does ajax request and getting some info, so it uses some `$http` or `$resource` or `Restangular` or something like that. 
Almost all of them could work with `Promises` or `Q`, so basically you need to make a chain of method calls

like

```
// $scope.FetchAllEmployeeData = function(){ return $http.get(....)};
$scope.FetchAllEmployeeData().then($scope.ClearMessages);
```